# Failed tx/swap, 5 UNI in limbo, no Transfer Event Emitted. How to get UNI unstuck?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, uniswap, pancakeswap

I attempted to swap 5 UNI for 40something SHI3lD. Tx failed, execution reverted but UNI wasnt sent back. 2nd Tx: 5 UNI for 41SHI3LD was successful. But I thought the 2nd would use the missing 5 UNI from the 1st Tx, it didnt.
15UNI prior to anything
5 UNI failed swap(now missing, no transfer event)
5 UNI successfully swapped after above
5 UNI leftover
Where could this UNI have gone? Failed swaps should fully revert, as they have always done for me. But where did the UNI get sent to? How did it send them without emitting a Transfer Event?
Looking at https://polygon-explorer-mainnet.chainstacklabs.com/tx/0x8b8dabf37bfb002660dbfb88dccfeb7fedc0c1c15646eab5d6ad5cf65a622579/internal-transactions
shows it is waiting for an internal transaction to complete, even though the original Tx failed. What could it be possibly waiting on, and what would be the solution to get these 5 UNI unstuck?
Please dont refer to the 2nd, successful swap, as I have the funds from that and it is irrelevant to the first, but you will see it when looking at my Tx History.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Already answered in a question you have deleted, the transaction history shows that 5 UNI is the correct balance https://polygonscan.com/token/0xb33eaad8d922b1083446dc23f610c2567fb5180f?a=0xc5145d3747ce0797444802b8d5608946fdf2b70d. A reverted transactions do not cause any change in the blockchain https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x8b8dabf37bfb002660dbfb88dccfeb7fedc0c1c15646eab5d6ad5cf65a622579. The transaction was mined on 2021-09-10, once mined the changes are immediate, there's no pending state change for later. I'm sure polygon-explorer message is about the explorer not the blockchain.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your answer but it doesnt tell me how an ERC20 transfer could occur without an Event being emitted. Hence why you cannot see the transfer on polygonscan, as it READS emitted EVENTS.